# "whether" or "If"

Tags: grammar

Are both the sentences correct?

I don't care whether you're married or single.

I don't care if you're married or single.

When to use whether over if?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

1) We use **whether and not if** after prepositions:

```
*Later I argued with the doctor about whether I had hit my head, since I couldn’t remember feeling it.*

Not: *Later I argued with the doctor about if I had hit my head …*

*The police seemed mainly interested in whether there were any locks on the windows.*
Not: *The police seemed mainly interested in if there were any locks …*
```

2)     We use **whether**, not if, **before to-infinitives**:

```
*I don’t know whether to buy* the blue one or the red one.
```

3)     We use whether, not if, **after prepositions**:

[talking about a trip to Australia for a year]

```
We’re not interested in whether we get great jobs and that kind of thing, we just want to have a good time.
```

4)     We use whether, not if, directly before or not:

```
*Can you tell me whether or not you’re interested in the job.*
```

(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether)

I your case I would use **whether or not**, e.g.: I do not care whether she is married or not.